# Can you prevent entering of 'periods' or 'dots' in a numbers input field on an Android webView using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, dom-events, keyup

I have a javascript application loaded into an Android webView. 
I have a table on the screen with items and next to the items are input fields where users enter their received quantities.
We don't want people to use decimals but only whole numbers.

Is there a way to do this in an Android webview? All the special characters are showing a code or 229.
I really want to prevent [.][,][-][ ]
Right now I am trying:

```
$(document).on("keyup", "tr", ".rtqy-input", function(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which || e.charCode;
    toastr.info(code);
            if(code == 229){
                console.log(e);
                return false; 
            }
        return true;
    }
});
```

I'm not really able to get anything to happen.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Hey First check jquery is working or not.by alert method place in$( document ).ready(function() {
    alert( "ready!" );
}); .IF it works then change from $(document).on to $('.rtqy-input').on ,I trhink rtqy-input is a class

Comment: It works, so the keyboard I am using is an Android keyboard. When I hit a period, comma or dash, I can see in a console log that the code is 229. I've tried keyup, keypress, keydown and none seem to work...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure for Android Webview and its' keyCode, but when you want to prevent user from inputting character in input field with Javascript, you need to use 'keydown' event instead of 'keyup' event. Try changing event parameter in your on() function.

Comment: I tried that and got the same result. I can remove the dot after its been entered but I can't prevent it from showing up when pressed. I am trying to pretty much disable periods, dashes and commas in an input field with a type "number"

Comment: did you tried event.preventDefault() instead of return false?

Comment: Yes, it didn't work. The keycodes on android are hard to work with. I passed this issue on to someone else to look at. I'll post a solution on here if we can figure this out!

Comment: @leenbean16 Good luck! Looks like this has been infamous for long time. There is an thread with this https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118639#c259  Maybe someone could get some hints from there

Comment: Its a tough one... Ill pass the link along. Thank you!